# Local dev environment, php & mysql work, but not together

Tags: php, mysql, apache, windows-7, localhost

I've spent the whole day trying to set up development environment using:

- PHP Version 5.3.3
- apache 2.2
- mySQL Server 5.1
- Windows 7

The localhost renders the php fine, and I can work with mySQL via the command line client, but **whenever I try to interact with mySQL through PHP I get a 30 second "waiting for localhost" and then a blank white browser**.

- I've tried running tests scripts that just connect to the database.
- I've tried loggin-in via phpMyAdmin using 'root' and the correct password.
- The mySQL service IS running.
- No entries in the server error-log associated with the failed connection.
- I have the line "extension=php_mysql.dll" in my php.ini file and when I run "phpinfo()" all the mySQL information shows up.
- ".../php" and ".../MySQL Server 5.1/bin" are included in my PATH.

I basically followed the instructions [here](http://www.bicubica.com/apache-php-mysql/index.php) to set the whole thing up.  I've tried everything I can think of twice so any fresh ideas would be greatly appreciated.

This is the code I'm using to connect to the database:

```
    <?php

# Define MySQL Settings
define("MYSQL_HOST", "localhost");
define("MYSQL_USER", "root");
define("MYSQL_PASS", "devpass");
define("MYSQL_DB", "test");

$conn = mysql_connect("".MYSQL_HOST."", "".MYSQL_USER."", "".MYSQL_PASS."") or die(mysql_error());
mysql_select_db("".MYSQL_DB."",$conn) or die(mysql_error());

$sql = "SELECT * FROM test";
$res = mysql_query($sql);

while ($field = mysql_fetch_array($res))
{
$id = $field['id'];
$name = $field['name'];

echo 'ID: ' . $field['id'] . '<br />';
echo 'Name: ' . $field['name'] . '<br /><br />';
}
?>
```

It's strait out of the example from the link I posted.  'test' is a valid DB.

Comment: Can you post the code that you're using to connect to the database?

Comment: Can you connect using the mysql client? You might need to set up the mysql sock

Comment: Install Ubuntu, then install Apache, PHP and MySQL. Even Steve Jobs says, "It just works."

Comment: If you must develop on Windoze (barf) then for future reference you may want to give WAMP (http://www.wampserver.com/en/) a try.  That is what I have used in the past (thankfully) for deving on a Windoze box.

Comment: @NullUserException, Yes I can connect using the mysql client.  What kept me from using WAMP is I'm planning on adding python to the mix as well.  Would WAMP allow for that?

Comment: @CMike Yes, you can add python. But I would try and solve the problem because these prepackaged AMP servers all have issues.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the problem was, but I started over using the directions from [www.webdevelopersnotes.com](http://www.webdevelopersnotes.com/how-do-i/install-apache-windows-7.php) and was able to get it all working.

Happy Day!

Anybody else looking to go through the set up I would suggest following these directions.  They seem to be the most up to date and explain a lot more "why" than the other sites I found.

Answer (score 0):

try using [WAMP](http://www.wampserver.com/en/) or [XAMPP](http://www.apachefriends.org/en/xampp.html)

Comment: I plan on also adding python to the mix, does WAMP allow for that?

Answer (score 0):

This is a problem with the default hosts file in windows 7 (or with MySQL's lack of IPv6 support).  You will need to replace the IPv6 loopback with an IPv4 loopback instead.

Open `C:\Windows\System32\drivers\etc\hosts` with admin privileges (if necessarily, you can temporarily de-protected it).

Find IPv6: `::1   localhost`

Change to IPv4: `127.0.0.1   localhost`

Comment: I don't doubt that was the problem, but I can't attempt the fix since I started the process over and got it working as per the response above.  Thanks for the post.